# URL of collection is specified but it returns error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection on myapp.com/groups looking like this:

```
[   {
    "_id": "52dd2bd1044bf96a12ed2319",
    "name": "US",
    "id": 1,
    "users": []   },   {
    "_id": "52dd2bd1044bf96a12ed231b",
    "name": "BR",
    "id": 3,
    "users": []   },   {
    "_id": "52dd2bd1044bf96a12ed231c",
    "name": "SK",
    "id": 4,
    "users": []   },   {
    "_id": "52dd2bd1044bf96a12ed231d",
    "name": "CZ",
    "id": 5,
    "users": []   },   {
    "_id": "52dd2bd2044bf96a12ed231e",
    "name": "UK",
    "id": 6,
    "users": []   } ]
```

Then I have backbone model and collection:

```
Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'groups',
    });

Groups = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'groups',
        model: Group
    });
```

And I'd like to create an instance of collection like this:

```
groups = new Groups();

groups.fetch();
```

But I always get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'url' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: You can try to add the slash before `url: '/groups',`

Comment: Have you ever override the Collection's sync method?I think there might be a mistake.

Comment: I didn't override Collection's sync and have a slash `url: '/groups'`, but error is still the same.

Comment: What `Backbone` plugins do you use?

Comment: I'm using backbone.maironette and backbone.syphon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

javascript

```
var Group = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Groups = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Group,
    url: "groups",
    parse: function(data) {
        return data;
    }
});
var GroupView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.collection = new Groups();
        this.collection.fetch({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(collection, response) {
                var template = _.template(yourViewTemplate, {
                    groups: that.collection.models
                });
                that.$el.html(template);
            },
            error: function(collection, response) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

    }
});
```

html

```
<% _.each(groups, function(group) { %>
   <%= group.get('_id') %>
   <%= group.get('name') %>
   <%= group.get('id') %>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Puigcerber noted, the most likely cause of this is that you haven't prepended your url (`groups`) with a forward slash. Backbone is *very* opinionated about a few things, and the `url` property is one of them. Try updating your `url` property for the `Groups` collection to `/groups`.

It could be an accidental `Backbone.Sync` override as Rocky Lee put it, but I'd wager my car that it's the `url` property angering the Backbone gods.

Comment: I have there slash `url: '/groups'`, I'm using freshly downloaded Backbone.js and Marionette.js and I'm not extending Backbone.Sync in my app.

Comment: Interesting... I've never used Marionette.js, though I've wanted to. If I were you right now, I'd start debugging this by removing any and all complexity from the application. Disable/comment out Marionette and try it with just the **absolute minimum** required to run your app. It's much, much more difficult to debug without taking out all the variables.

Comment: I still have an error - Uncaught TypeError: Property 'url' of object [object Object] is not a function.

Comment: I am starting to think it's because you are defining `urlRoot` and `url` simultaneously. Backbone is very opinionated about REST API design, and it will automatically build the model URLs based on the `url` property provided to the collection. It could very easily be that the `url` property it automatically assigns the models during that process is conflicting with the `urlRoot` property for the models. @ladislav_prague